# Название элемента пластиковой бутылки

Tags: названия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как называется эта полоса из пластика под крышкой, обнимающая горлышко?

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Крышки для ПЭТ (полиэтилентерефталат) бутылок классифицируются на стандартные (винтовые пластиковые пробки **с контролем вскрытия**) и колпачки для закрывания тары с носиками и выдвижными клапанами, позволяющими употребить продукт без снятия крышки. [Продукция такого типа особо популярна у спортсменов и любителей активного отдыха. К подвиду колпачков можно отнести крышки *push-pull* (с удобным дозатором) и *flip-top* (с откидным клапаном).]

Наша крышка крепится на горле бутылки с помощью винтовой резьбы. "Главное предназначение" крышки — обеспечение герметичности и возможность многократного использования.
Основную роль в крышке для ПЭТ бутылки играет **отрывное кольцо** — «предохранитель».
С особенностями исполнения запирающего замка (отрывного кольца) можно ознакомиться здесь: [Укупорочные изделия](http://polymery.ru/production.php?cat_id=101).